# Any problems returning BSON to mobile devices?

Tags: json, http, mobile, bson

I am currently working writing some services for consumption with mobile devices iphone apps, etc. So what is very important to me is the pay load being returned from my http services to the devices, I need it as small as possible. So I went with json for this.

However I have come across another type that is meant to be 25% less in size on average - [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/)

Has anyone worked with this and are there pros and cons of using it instead of JSON? The data being returned from the http service are mostly simple objects with a number of properties of complex types, or possible a list of objects.

Or is there another data type I should be looking at that may cut the payload further?

Answer (score 6):

I did some performance tests on Android 3.2 with JSON and BSON. The frameworks I used were gson and bson4jackson. The server is a Java REST API, built with Jersey. In the scenario i marshalled a Java object on the client to JSON/BSON, sent it via HTTP to the server, unmarshalled it and responded with 200 OK if the unmarshalling process succeeded.

The result was, that BSON was faster at bigger files (at ~120 kb or more), at small files JSON was clearly faster.

The reason is that BSON extends the data format with some additional data to accelerate the parsing, which leads to a bigger file size, especially for small documents.

I tried the same with iOS, but i couldn't find a (working) BSON framework to decode BSON. BSONKit throws errors for some elements on iOS. If someone knows another working framework i would be glad to if you can tell me.

BTW: The packing rate was also better with JSON, up to a size of ~135 kb. IMHO you should only use BSON if you ONLY have to deal with big files, because 120 kb or more is a very big size for a conventional request between a mobile device and a server.

Comment: If you'd still like to try these tests on iOS, feel free to try ObjCMongoDB, of which I'm author, which now supports iOS. You can contact me if you run into trouble.